# Typescript - null array reference

Tags: angular, typescript, service, ngoninit

I'm writting application in typescript/angular and i have a service which get json with data and i'd like to display this downoad objects, but it can occur that objects can be more than i can display in one html component so i should split this array of objects. By the way before that i should filtering all objects from json by ip address, so i write component like that:

```
export class ServerBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  pods = new Array<Pod>();

  @Input() node_s: NodeServer;

  getPods() {
    // console.log('Download pods');
    this.httpService.getPods().subscribe(data => {
      this.pods = data.items;
    });
    console.log('Download status: ' + this.pods.length);
  }

  filtering() {
    console.log('Node_s length: ' + this.node_s.status.addresses[1].address);
    console.log('Node_s length: ' + this.pods.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.pods.length; i++) {
      if (this.node_s.status.addresses[0].address === this.pods[i].status.hostIP) {
        console.log(this.pods[i].metadata.name);
        // this.node_s.podArray.push(this.pods[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getPods();
    // this.filtering();
  }

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) { }

}
```

but i can't use filtering function because the pods array is empty, but why??

Comment: When you call `this.getPods();` the `pods` array will be populated eventually. If you call your `filtering()` before the `getPods()` has populated the array, it will be empty

Comment: It's executing asynchronously. This.filtering() is being executed before this.getPods() completes. Async operation is in action! Use promises to execute those functions in sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coz of the `async` behaviour, Your code should look like this:

```
this.httpService.getPods().subscribe(data => {
    this.pods = data.items;
    console.log('Download status: ' + this.pods.length); // call it here
    this.filtering(); // function should be called from here
});
```

---

> For more detail please follow `// Execution Flow : #number` , this way
>   the whole execution flow will be executed

```
getPods() {
    // Execution Flow : 2
    this.httpService.getPods().subscribe(data => { 
        this.pods = data.items; // Execution Flow : 6
    });
    console.log('Download status: ' + this.pods.length); // Execution Flow : 3
}

// Execution Flow : 5
filtering() {
    console.log('Node_s length: ' + this.node_s.status.addresses[1].address);
    console.log('Node_s length: ' + this.pods.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.pods.length; i++) {
        if (this.node_s.status.addresses[0].address === this.pods[i].status.hostIP) {
            console.log(this.pods[i].metadata.name);
            // this.node_s.podArray.push(this.pods[i]);
        }
    }
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getPods(); // Execution Flow : 1
    this.filtering(); // Execution Flow : 4
}
```

Comment: Ok it's work, but now i have another problem, when i try to push this filtering object to array i have an error like this: ERROR TypeError: Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference

Comment: That error means you are pushing nothing into the array. You are trying to push Null value.

Comment: @AdKossa , all you need is to initialize the array in which you are trying to push data , you must be just declaring the array bu not initialising it